# Running Vue dev, giving me promise rejection

Tags: node.js, vue.js, promise, unhandled-exception

When I run vue's npm run dev, I got this error:

```
(node:10871) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Exited with code 3
```

It works fine if I run in my computer with Node 6.11.3
But fails when I deploy to AWS EC2 with Node 6.11.3, or the Latest Node 9.something

If I run with latest node, I got a detail error message:

```
(node:10429) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Exited with code 3
    at ChildProcess.cp.once.code (/home/ubuntu/loan-vue-frontend/node_modules/opn/index.js:84:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:272:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:936:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:353:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:541:12)
(node:10429) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10429) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have tried just installing a new project from scratch and it works.

Then I compare the code, and I found out I have this code (in a file called 'build/dev-server.js' :

```
var _resolve
var readyPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
  _resolve = resolve
})

console.log('> Starting dev server...')
devMiddleware.waitUntilValid(() => {
  console.log('> Listening at ' + uri + '\n')
  // when env is testing, don't need open it
  if (autoOpenBrowser && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'testing') {
    opn(uri)
  }
  _resolve()
})

var server = app.listen(port)

module.exports = {
  ready: readyPromise,
  close: () => {
    server.close()
  }
}
```

It seems to me the readyPromise is the cause of trouble.
But the only place that call that dev-server.js is in package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
  }
```

I suspect

> ready: readyPromise,

is not right because 'ready' may not have a catch block.  but I have no clue how I can fix it if that's the case.

Any idea?

Comment: `ready` don't need catch block because it can't be rejected. `opn(uri)` need catch block because rejection is happening inside in line 84 https://github.com/sindresorhus/opn/blob/master/index.js#L84

Comment: Yes.. You are absolutely correct!  man. open() need the atch() block.  thank you so much!!!!!